# Selenium c# SendKeys vs manual Input - different behavior of tested webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My goal is to automatically test an "register new user " webpage. When registering manually (without selenium) the result page has a different behavior than after registerering using the selenium script.

I use 
    `foreach (var c in message) { target.SendKeys(c.ToString());}`

to input the characters into the text fields.

It seems that somehow the framework the website is built on recognizes that a script is doing the registration. I wonder if there is any other way than using target.SendKeys to avoid a different behavior of the website when using selenim instead of manual testing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: My goal is to automatically test an "register new user " webpage.
When registering manually (without selenium) the result page has a different behavior than after registerering using the selenium script. 

foreach (var c in message)
            { target.SendKeys(c.ToString());}

to input the characters into the text fields.

It seems that somehow the framework the website is built on recognizes that a script is doing the registration.
I wonder if there is any other way than using target.SendKeys to avoid a different behavior of the website when using selenim instead of manual testing.

Comment: My guess is that the field you are typing into is validating/processing each keypress and Selenium sends all text at once.

Comment: even if i use target.SendKeys for each single letter?